# Accessing pre-defined list for constraints

Tags: python, pyomo

I am trying to solve a optimization problem with Pyomo. The problem is to minimize an objective function constrained over a pre-defined list.

```
lambda = [0, 1, 2]

x-> Independent Variable
y = f(x)

Constraints:
y[0] < lambda[0]
y[1] < lambda[1]
y[2] < lambda[2]

Obj = minimize (model.y)
```

So basically my optimization result will have three elements. While defining constraints for the same, how do i access the list? i.e. First element of model.y should be less than the first element of lambda. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about like this?
Set the lambda as a parameter of Set A:

```
data:

set A := L1 L2 L3 ;
param Lambda: x y z;

pyomo:
model.A=Set()
model.Lambda = Param(model.A)   
model.Y=Var(model.A)
```